# How do I align text/images on bottom/right/center/middle of a container using the blueprint css framework?

Tags: vertical-alignment, blueprint-css, alignment

Is there some easy way to align stuff in div containers to the right or bottom:

```
<div class="span-24 align-right last">Text appears on the right side of the layout</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="span-2" id="lots-of-content"></div><div class="span-22 last bottom">Appears at bottom of container</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="span-24 vertical-middle last">Middle of the container</div>
```

Here's a sample of what I'm working with trying to position the "topnav" below:

```
     <div class="container"> 
        <div class="span-16">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="span-8 last vertical-middle">
            <div id="topnav" class="align-right"><input type="button" id="register" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="Register" /> or <button type="button" id="signin" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Sign in</button></div>
        </div>
        <hr />
...
     </div>
```

Comment: You need to add `position: relative` to the container DIV; see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position: absolute`.  For example:

```
.align-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
/* Or, alternatively, */
.align-right {
    float: right;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.vertical-middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Note that for `vertical-middle`, this will center the *top edge* of the content, no the content itself.

Make sure that the containing `DIV` is `position: relative` to force it to become the offset parent (which the position of the children are relative to)  **EDIT**: In other words, add the following rule:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: all but .align-right { float: right; } seem to be positioning based on the viewport (browser window) and not the container.  For instance, align-right bottom, displays at the right edge of the viewport all the way at the bottom of the screen.  If I could get it within the container I'd be golden.  :)

Comment: Thanks for taking a second look, I'll retry.